# mysql query to count no of rows in joining three tables and count rows of one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem in **MYSQL** query.
I have three tables one is voucher table other clients and third is voucher_client.
In voucher_client table I have voucher `id` column that relate to voucher table and I want to count related rows from client table.
Like if voucher table has `id` 2 and voucher clients are 2 then query will check from client table `age_group` column where `age_group` is adult ,child or infant 
here some pictures of tables for more detail.
Please help me out

**Voucher table**

[image]

**Client table**

[image]

**Voucher client table**

[image]

I am trying to do like this

```
  SELECT `v`.*, `a`.`name` as `agent_name`, COUNT(CASE WHEN c.age_group = 'Adult' THEN c.id END) AS t_adult, COUNT(CASE WHEN c.age_group = 'Child' THEN c.id END) AS t_child, COUNT(CASE WHEN c.age_group = 'Infant' THEN c.id END) AS t_infant, COUNT(c.id) as total FROM `voucher` `v` JOIN `voucher_client` `vc` ON `vc`.`voucher_id`=`v`.`id` JOIN `client` `c` ON `vc`.`client_id`=`c`.`id` JOIN `tbl_users` `a` ON `a`.`userId`=`v`.`agent_id` LEFT JOIN `voucher_hotel` `vh` ON `vh`.`voucher_id`=`v`.`id` WHERE `v`.`isDeleted` =0 GROUP BY `v`.`id` ORDER BY `v`.`id` DESC
```

expected output like this

```
voucher_id t_adult    t_child    t_infant
 1            2           0         0
 2            1           0         0
```

Comment: Please don't post images for sample data instead include sample data in textual format or better to use any online tool, Also include your complete table definitions and expected output

Comment: What output gives your query?

Comment: Your query should give you correct result. What is wrong in the output? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2bcf5/2

Comment: complete query is updated another is hotel table that is in left join because i want to join that table partiely if data exist or not in hotel table data must be shown. problem is due to that left join

Comment: What is the data in 'tbl_users' table? Also, what is 'agent_id' in voucher table for voucher ids 1 and 2?

Comment: in tbl_users data of agents and agent_id are 1 ,2 etc. i think problem is in joining of voucher hotel that i want to join left join because i want that if data exist or not in voucher table voucher data must be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only want to show `v.id` in the result, then replace `v.*` by `v.id` in the query.

(Btw, most databases wouldn't even allow a `*` when there's group by. MySql deviates from the ANSI SQL standard in that aspect.)

And if you need to join to an extra table with an 1-N relationship? Then you can count the distinct values. So that the totals only reflect the unique clientid's.

```sql
SELECT
  v.id AS voucher_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.age_group = 'Adult'  THEN c.id END) AS t_adult,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.age_group = 'Child'  THEN c.id END) AS t_child,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.age_group = 'Infant' THEN c.id END) AS t_infant
  -- , COUNT(*) as total
  -- , COUNT(c.id) as total_clientid -- count on value doesn't count NULL's
  -- , COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) as total_unique_clientid
FROM voucher v
JOIN voucher_client vc ON vc.voucher_id = v.id
JOIN client c ON c.id = vc.client_id
-- LEFT JOIN voucher_hotel vh ON vh.voucher_id = v.id
WHERE v.isDeleted = 0
--  AND c.age_group = 'Adult' -- uncomment this to only count the adults
GROUP BY v.id 
ORDER BY v.id
```

Comment: complete query is updated another is hotel table that is in left join because i want to join that table partiely if data exist or not in hotel table data must be shown. problem is due to that left join

Comment: @NadeemIjaz So there are now 2 tables added to that query. `tbl_users` and `voucher_hotel`.  I've added a DISTINCT before the CASE WHEN's. That way it'll count only the unique clientid's, which were multiplied by that extra left join.

Comment: what will be the new query @LukStorms please help

Comment: @NadeemIjaz You should add that voucher_hotel table to your question with some sample data.  And then change your query by adding a criteria for it in the WHERE clause. Because just joining to a 1-N relationship without using it's data would seem pointless.  And I have a hunch that the hotel_id also then has to be added to the group by? I'm also wondering if this actually needs a `... from voucher_hotel right join voucher ...` instead.  Also, does the expected results then remain the same?  And have you tried the effect of those `... COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ...` that were added?